# Infinite Ajax Scroll redirecting to another page

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code is working but when I scroll down it is not infinite scroll, it redirects to another page, what am I missing ? i am trying to integrate http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/

```
<div id="base-container">
        <!-- loop row data -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
               <center><p><img src='images/portfolio-img1.jpg' alt='portfolio img' style='max-height: 240px; max-width: 360px;'/></p></center><br>
               <center><p><img src='images/portfolio-img1.jpg' alt='portfolio img' style='max-height: 240px; max-width: 360px;'/></p></center><br>
               <center><p><img src='images/portfolio-img1.jpg' alt='portfolio img' style='max-height: 240px; max-width: 360px;'/></p></center><br>
            </div>
        </div>

      <ul id="pagination">
                        <li class=""><a href="/page1.php">1</a></li>
                        <li class="next"><a href="/page2.html">2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/biyahero/js/js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var ias = $.ias({
          container:  "#base-container",
          item:       ".item",
          pagination: "#pagination",
          next:       ".next a",
          delay:      1000
        });

        ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
        ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({ offset: 100 }));
        ias.extension(new IASPagingExtension());
        ias.extension(new IASHistoryExtension({ prev: '.prev a' }));
      </script>
```

Comment: So problem is still there?

Comment: Yes still not working.